# How to Programm A Dialog box with a typewriter effect in Java?

Tags: java, animation, text, effect

Im am very new to java and programming so I might be a bit annoying to work with but please bear with me :D So As the title says I'm trying to figure out how to properly program a working dialog box with typing text animation for a game I'm working on. I've seen some posts about swing timers but Im having trouble properly understanding them. If anybody has an idea please share it!

Comment: What GUI technology are you using?

Comment: Welcome BaconDevil Gamming, this site is using a question and answer format and is not intended for long discussions or help sessions. Please, either consider asking at e.g. www.gamedev.net or reformat your question so it can be answered more easily within a single answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you don't already know the basics of Java, you should learn them first. :)

When you have, you will need some kind of graphics library.

---

I know that LWJGL is a good graphics library.

[LWJGL Link :)](https://www.lwjgl.org)

According to some people over at stack overflow, Minecraft was made with this.

---

**But**, as I said it's  probably best (if you don't already know this) to learn the basics of Java first.